# What is the meaning of red colored <> icon on cloud9

Tags: cloud9-ide

What is the meaning of this red icon that is placed on the left handside of Annotation.xml file?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just the icon for the XML file type in Cloud9.